# Jquery - check if element is not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the value of a div and then output it using jquery. However, it doesn't seems to work.

Here is my code:

```
    <div id="container">
        <p id="textbit"></p>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
        var barcode = $('#textbit');
        var container = $('#container');

        setTimeout(function() {barcode.text('1233')}, 5000);


        barcode.each(function() {
            if (barcode.html().length > 0) {
                var codereader = barcode.text();
                container.hide(100);

                alert('The code is '+ codereader);
            }
        });

        });
      </script>
```

It works when I don't have the setTimeout function but this div will be populated dynamically using AJAX in future.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So set your logic in ajax relevant callback (success?) once element content has been modified

Comment: please use jquery dynamic events..and dynamic function calls..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is single threaded and `setTimeout` function is an asynchronous function. It doesn't delay the code execution for 5000ms as you think. It only schedules the callback function to be executed after a 5000ms.

After scheduling the callback to be executed, javascript will keep executing the code below the `setTimeout` function. After 5000ms when the callback is executed, the code below the `setTimeoutYou` is already executed. When you try to fetch the value, the html is not set yet as it's been scheduled to set after 5000ms.

If you want to simulate AJAX time delay, you may move the code for getting value into a new function and call it in the `settimeout` callback like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var barcode = $('#textbit');
    var container = $('#container');

    var success = function(){
        barcode.each(function() {
        if (barcode.html().length > 0) {
            var codereader = barcode.text();
            container.hide(100);

            alert('The code is '+ codereader);
        }
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
       barcode.text('1233');
       success();
    });

   }, 5000);

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case you need to check in the "done" promise which will be executed after the AJAX completes.

similarly like this .

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var barcode = $('#textbit');
var container = $('#container');

setTimeout(function() {
    barcode.text('1233');
    barcode.each(function() {
        if (barcode.html().length > 0) {
            var codereader = barcode.text();
            container.hide(100);

            alert('The code is '+ codereader);
        }
    });
}, 5000);
});
```

Ajax is a asynchronous, the execution will continue to next line, and later point when it completes. The callback provided will be executed. You need to make this execution in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

**use ajax complete event: when ajax will finish its task then this code will run**

complete: function( xhr, status ) {

```
    alert( "The request is complete! now u can get other function form here" );
    getvalues();
}
```